# Explanation needed for a regex for insertion postitions of thousands separators

Tags: regex

Can someone explain to me how this regex expression character by character finds the character places to put commas in a number. For clarification, I understand the basics of regexes and how lookaheads and lookbehinds work. I just do not understand how this regex matches the positions in a number where commas are supposed to go. A character by character explanation would be appreciated.

```
(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))
```

How would it match comma positions in a number like `1234567`?

Tried looking online and watching videos but does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to replace each match of the regular expression

```
(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))
```

with a comma.<sup>1</sup> To do this we would use an appropriate method or function supported by the language being used. In Ruby, for example, if the string were held by the variable `str` one would write:

```
str.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, ',')
```

---

Suppose the string were

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
^
```

The regex engine maintains string pointers. I will consider the one that keeps track of the current location in the string where a match is being attempted. Initially it is located immediately before the first character of the string, as I have indicated above. The gaps shown are not space characters, but represent locations *between* successive characters. Regular expressions can be written to match these locations alone, in which case they are referred to as *zero-width matches*.

The engine attempts a match. The regex begins with the *positive lookbehind* `(?<=\d)`, which asserts that the string pointer's location is immediately preceded by a digit. That assertion fails because no character precedes the current location of the pointer.

---

The pointer is now advanced one character position:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ^
```

The positive lookbehind, `(?<=\d)`, is now satisfied, and will remain satisfied as the string pointer is advanced. The engine now evaluates the *positive lookahead* `(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))`, which breaks down as follows:

```
(?=           begin a positive lookahead
  (\d\d\d)    match 3 digits and save it to capture group 1
  +           execute the preceeding match of three characters one or
              more times, as many times as possible
  (?!         begin a negative lookahead
    \d        match a digit
  )           end negative lookahead
)             end positive lookahead
```

The engine now attempts to match `(\d\d\d)+` from the current string position. It is successful in doing so, matching `'234567'`.

The `+` token instructs the engine to execute `(\d\d\d)` one or more times,  as many times as possible ("greedily") . Accordingly, it matches `'234'`, saving it to capture group 1, then `'567'`, over-writing the contents of capture group 1 with `'567'`.<sup>2</sup>

The engine then attempts to satisfy the *negative lookahead* `(?!\d)`, which asserts that `'234567'` is not followed by a digit. As we are now at the end of string, that assertion is satisfied, causing the positive lookahead to be satisfied, resulting in the regex matching the zero-width location between the first two digits.

---

The string pointer is advanced by one character:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  , ^
```

I have indicated where the comma corresponding to the first match will be inserted.

As before the positive lookbehind asserting that previous character is a digit (here `'2'`) is satisfied.

`(\d\d\d)+` within the positive lookahead matches `'345'`, but no more, since  `\d\d\d` does not match `'67'`. The negative lookahead `(?!\d)` now fails because a digit (`'6'`) follows `'345'`. Hence, the positive lookahead fails, so the entire match fails.

---

The string pointer is advanced:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ,   ^
```

Again, the positive lookbehind is satisfied but the positive lookahead is not, as `(\d\d\d)+` matches `'456'`, but the negative lookahead fails because `'456'` is followed by a digit.

---

The string pointer is advanced:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ,     ^
```

`(\d\d\d)+` matches `'567'` and the negative lookahead is satisfied because no digit (in fact, no character) follows that match. The positive lookahead therefore succeeds, resulting in the regex matching the zero-width location between the fourth and fifth characters of the string, so a comma is inserted there.

---

The string pointer is advanced:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ,     , ^
```

`(\d\d\d)+` fails to match `'67'` so the match at this location fails.

---

The string pointer is advanced:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ,     ,   ^
```

`(\d\d\d)+` fails to match `'7'` so the match as this location fails.

---

The string pointer is advanced:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ,     ,     ^
```

`(\d\d\d)+` fails to match an empty string so the match as this location fails, completing the regex engine's work.

<sup>1. Depending on the language, it may be necessary to set the regex's so-called "general" (g) flag, meaning that it should not return until all matches in the string have been attempted.</sup>

<sup>2. The contents of the capture group is of no interest here. Many languages support a construct known as a *non-capture group*, here written `(?:\d\d\d)`. It accepts *quantifiers*, here `+`, just as capture groups do, but does not save the match. Non-capture groups should be used when grouping is being done for the sole purpose of applying a qualifier. Using a capture group in such situations works, but it may mislead the reader to expect that the contents of the capture group will be used later in the calculations (reasoning that a non-capture group would have been used otherwise).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Commas are supposed to be inserted at positions where digits in multiples of 3 follow, so you have a `(\d\d\d)+` in a lookahead pattern `(?=...)`, but you don't want another digit to follow those digits in multiples of 3 because then they will actually not be a multple of 3, so you make a negative lookahead assertion of `(?!\d)` after `(\d\d\d)+` (so it won't match the position right before `4567` in `1234567` even though there are 3 digits after the position). Finally, a comma should be preceded by at least a digit so you make a positive lookbehind assertion of `(?<=\d)` before where the comma is supposed to go.